# Pandas - Datetime format change to '%m/%d/%Y'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

Hello there stackoverflow community,

I would like to change the datetime format of a column, but I doesn't work and I don't know what I'am doing wrong.

After executing the following code:

```
df6['beginn'] = pd.to_datetime(df6['beginn'], unit='s', errors='ignore')
```

I got this output, and thats fine, but i would like to take out the hour to have only `%m/%d/%Y` left.

```
ID       DATE
91060    2017-11-10 00:00:00
91061    2022-05-01 00:00:00
91062    2022-04-01 00:00:00
Name: beginn, Length: 91063, dtype: object
```

I've tried this one and many others

```
df6['beginn'] = df6['beginn'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

and get the following output:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.
```

But I don't understand why, I've transformed the data with `pd.to_datetime` or not?

Appreciate any hint you can give me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you use errors='ignore' so you have some non-datetime64 objects left in the column. The column dtype is still `object`.

Comment: The problem is, when I take  'errors='ignore'' out, the code doesn't work :/  Could it be, that the header 'DATE' is the problem?

Comment: `strftime` is transfer`str` to `datetime`, the col you have there is a `datetime` object so `pandas` outputs `AttributeError`. you can use `df6['beginn'] = df6['beginn'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime('you desire output'))`

Comment: Try using `errors="coerce"` (invalid parsing will be set as NaT)  instead of `ignore` ?

Comment: @creanion that isn't the column dtype. That is the dataframe type. But you are right that there are still some non-datetime64 objects in there.

Comment: It shows name and dtype - Series have dtype and name (the kind I mean) and DataFrames have neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you have to use `errors="ignore"` is because not all the dates you are parsing are in the correct format. If you use `errors="coerce"` like @phi has mentioned then any dates that cannot be converted will be set to `NaT`. The columns datatype will still be converted to datatime64 and you can then format as you like and deal with the `NaT` as you want.

**Example**

A dataframe with one item in `Date` not written as Year/Month/Day (25th Month is wrong):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [91060, 91061, 91062, 91063], 'Date': ['2017/11/10', '2022/05/01', '2022/04/01', '2055/25/25']})
>>> df
      ID        Date
0  91060  2017/11/10
1  91061  2022/05/01
2  91062  2022/04/01
3  91063  2055/25/25

>>> df.dtypes
ID       int64
Date    object
dtype: object
```

Using `errors="ignore"`:

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='ignore')
>>> df
      ID        Date
0  91060  2017/11/10
1  91061  2022/05/01
2  91062  2022/04/01
3  91063  2055/25/25

>>> df.dtypes
ID       int64
Date    object
dtype: object
```

Column `Date` is still an object because not all the values have been converted. Running `df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` will result in the `AttributeError`

Using `errors="coerce"`:

```
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
>>> df
      ID       Date
0  91060 2017-11-10
1  91061 2022-05-01
2  91062 2022-04-01
3  91063        NaT

>>> df.dtypes
ID               int64
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Invalid dates are set to NaT and the column is now of type datatime64 and you can now format it:

```
>>> df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
>>> df
      ID        Date
0  91060  11/10/2017
1  91061  05/01/2022
2  91062  04/01/2022
3  91063         NaN
```

Note: When formatting datatime64, it is converted back to type object so NaT's are changed to NaN. The issue you are having is a case of some dirty data not in the correct format.